# Statistics: How to calculate Ordering from 1 to 5 of 3 different colors?

Tags: statistics

I have 5 colored sticks. 3 Red ones, 1 blue one, and 1 green one. How many different possibilities of order are there using anywhere from 1 stick to all 5 sticks?
I.E.
RRRGB
RRRG
RRR
RR
R
RRGBR
RGBRR
GBRRR
G
...
etc

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Yup, but I'm unfamiliar with this type of statistics so i need help.

Comment: This actually isn't about statistics, but about counting and combinations.  Anyway, did you try figuring out how many possibilities there are when you have 1 stick? 2? 3? There aren't huge numbers here so you may be able to just brute force this.  And when you start with short series you might see a pattern that generalizes for longer ones.

Comment: Is there a formula to do it easier than just writing out all the different combinations?

Comment: Probably ... but rather than just using a formula, I would recommend you play with this and hopefully discover some formula yourself!  That will lead to actual understanding of the formula, where it comes from, how it can be used or modified for other situations.  Everybody can plug in values into some formula .. I'd barely call that doing mathematics. You want to actually learn some mathematics?  You have to roll up your sleeves and do some work!

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how i learn. If everyone started from brick 1 in everything instead of learning on top of what others have learned we'd still be in the stone age. Knowing the formula is important for moving forward in understand how to do these problems. I can't make up my own formula, that would take too much time and be foolish.

Comment: Would it be 5!+4!+3!+2!+1!?

Answer (score 0):

So here are some guiding questions:

1. If you have 5 totally different sticks, how many way can you order them?
2. If all 5 of them are identical how is the number of distinct orders affect? (addition? subtraction? multiplication? division?)
3. If two of them are identical how is the number of distinct orders affected?
4. Finally, (which is your question) if three of them are identical how is the number of distinct orders affected?
5. Bonus question: if you now have 2 red sticks, 2 blue sticks and 1 green sticks. How many ways can you  arrange them? You should be able to get 30 very quickly if you have gotten the trick :)

Comment: If they're all different isn't it 5 factorial? I just need a formula - it seems it might not exist...

Comment: There is a formula. We are just trying to get to to reach it yourself because it's really simple.

Comment: So, when a teacher teaches a class do they start with "Hey kids, I have a formula for this problem, but i'm not going to tell you," or do they start with the formula and explain why and how it works? It's childish to tease me with such implications that "there is a formula... it's really simple."

Comment: Also the questions involve 3 identical sticks, and 2 of 2 different colors in any order from 1 to 5 sticks being used for each combination.

Comment: Uh my teachers don't teach the formula until the very end and that's how it has usually been unless the derivation is really beyond the level of study.